# How to scroll paragraph line by line in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text-widget

Hi I want to scroll paragraph line by line when user move to second line paragraph will scroll one line automatically i tried singlechild scrollview but it is not works

[image]

In Above Image when user type Ipsum then one line should be scroll up

any help will be appreciate

Comment: What was your approach with singlechildscrollview? Did you use any scrollController to manually scroll the scrollview?

Comment: I used singlechildscrollview because the Text widget does not support default scroll. I used default scroll controller to scroll text programmatically but it didn't give the desired result